# Is it possible to get rid of the Beggar's Coin?

Tags: occult-chronicles

I won a combat with a gargoyle, and much to my surprise, I still received a negative effect in my results cards... a Beggar's Coin.

[image]

This is like a double-dipping of pain. It lowers my Wands score by 1 while also taking up 2 points of Wands inventory space. And as far as I can tell, I can't drop it and couldn't refuse to pick it up.

Is there any way to get rid of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be other options, but the only method I've found so far is to die. While normally this ends the game and isn't much of a solution, if you have the major arcana card *Death*, you will be revived and the Beggar's Coin will no longer be in your inventory.